# What are the pre-processing requirements on cosine similarity?

Tags: similarity, cosine-similarity

The input on cosine similarity is two vectors representing two different data i want to compare. Is there a requirement for the semantic of the vector? Can it simply be  the byte representation of each file. And then compute the frequency of each byte? Does this make sense? Or there should be a vectorization of the file where each dimension is not a raw-piece of data from the file but some metadata as the frequency of each term if we speak for text files or the tf-idf encoding model? To put it in another shape: Does cosine similarity in order to be "correct" asks a complex pre-processing step of data or i can give it as input integer values that represents each byte of my data without text in mind or just a frequency term of each byte?

Answer (score 1):

The "semantics" of the data is critical.  For example, say you are comparing English text documents.  For large documents, the frequency of occurence of the various letters will be roughly the same, so if the elements of your vector represent the counts of letters, you will have trouble distinguishing documents.  If the elements of your vector represent the counts of words, you will get better results.  If the elements of your vector represent the counts of "stemmed" words, even better.  Etc.

Cosine similarity is a "dumb" statistical measure - it is up to you to give it something meaningful to compare.

Comment: What if i want to compare records and each vector consists of numerical data, boolean values and strings?I.e: [number][number][string][boolean]

Comment: @Curious - I'm not sure what you're asking.  Could you provide a brief example, showing some vector representations you're considering?

Comment: Suppose i have two records. r1=234,1023,No,Today is Sunday. and r2=876,423,Yes,Tomorrow i am leaving. How i can compute the cosine of those 2 records?How i can compute their vectors?I will just take char by char their ascii representation and make a vector? Then there is no semantic and cosine might give inaccurate results

Comment: @Curious - Each positional element of the vectors must measure a particular attribute/feature of the entities of interest.  In your example, maybe the elements represent 1) height, 2) weight, 3) does it eat meat 4) when it eats.  Because cosine similarity calculates based on numbers, you might have to convert non-numbers to numbers.  For example, you might use 0, 1 for booleans, and 1 - 7 for day of the week.  There are several problems with this approach.  For example, the scales of the numbers of the different attributes are different.  Also, you can't indicate day 1 is close to day 7.